How much time does it take to execute the methods without debugging each line?
Is it possible to see in Visual Studio or other utilies or programms how much time the following methods have been executed? This is a simplified version, but I have a lot of lines of code and it becomes hard to see how much time it took to execute method by method:
Foo foo = new ();
foo.Method_1(); // it takes 1 second to be executed
foo.Method_2(); // it takes 2 second to be executed
foo.Method_3(); // it takes 3 second to be executed

and its implementation:
public class Foo
{
    public void Method_1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    
    public void Method_2()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    
    public void Method_3()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}

Yeah, I know it is possible to see measurements while debugging:

But I want to execute a lot of code and I would like to see a list of methods which shows how much time it takes to execute code without debugging every piece of code. Is there any some tools in Visual Studio or maybe is alternative tools?

Sadly this question will likely be flagged as its asking for recommendations, but check out Visual Studio Profiling Tools, basically logs your apps performance when running on Release mode and serves you up lots of performance related data

It's a bit strange. @Narish did you notice this image is from the page you linked?

"I would like to see a list of methods which shows how much it takes to execute code" - That doesn't make as much sense as it sounds. First of all, you'll probably have parameters that affect the runtime of any one specific Method. That might be size of input, branches taken, if using interfaces the implementations behind those ... you may want to benchmark a particular method against a particular set of inputs or may want to have an "avergage" for plausibility and the tool to use depends on your goal regarding this.

@shingo maybe this is a Microsoft PysOp in motion? Good catch haha

@Fildor I believe it would be helpful for me because at first I will try to measure all methods with the same parameters.

There is a possible way that you can see a list of execution time of every method clearly but you must debug codes, using 'stopwatch' class to measure the execution time of each method as the following code, you can try to run it. I hope it can help you.
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Calls the Timewatch method, passing a method to execute as an argument
        Timewatch(Method_1);
        Timewatch(Method_2);
        Timewatch(Method_3);
    }
    static void Timewatch(Action method)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        // Execute the method passed in
        method();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("execution time：" + stopwatch.Elapsed);
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }
    static void Method_1()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // it takes 1 second to be executed
    }

    static void Method_2()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        // it takes 2 second to be executed
    }

    static void Method_3()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        // it takes 3 second to be executed
    }
}

What's more, you can also use Performance Profiler in Visual Studio to implement method level performance analysis.

upvoted! However, it requires to add a lot of code into an existing code. Is there some tools or utilities which can measure execution time without adding code?

You can measure execution time without adding code using Performance Profiler in Visual Studio. The path is Debug → Performance Profiler or press the shortcut key Alt+F2. If this doesn't work, finding third-party softwares or utilities may be a good option.

@Learner ​Have your problems been solved? Is there any other question?
